# How many Tesla Y are ordered/reserved so far

Tags: united-states, stocks, stock-analysis, stock-valuation

[Tesla Y](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla_Model_Y) is allowing to order ( similar to Tesla 3 reservation but allowing to choose configuration). I remember when Tesla 3 was announced there were plenty of information released by Tesla and 3rd parties that use to give information on how many Tesla 3 are reserved.
[One such example](https://electrek.co/2018/06/04/tesla-model-3-reservations-refunded-report/). Is there any publicly available information on how many Tesla Y are ordered. I was looking at [press release](https://ir.tesla.com/press-releases) but could not get that information. Can any one here please point me to that information?

I have two objectives that are related to personal finance.

1. To estimate the stock price, (simple investing) if a lot or orders than I may assume [higher profitability](https://electrek.co/2018/07/16/tesla-model-3-teardown-profitability/) so higher stock price and vice versa.
2. As I have ordered one Tesla Y one next day of its unveiling, I want to know how long my deposit $2500 will be tied up before I get the car. Also, I want to manage my cash flow with the possible time frame when I get the car, so I need to take less loan/no loan.

FYI, the **"pre-order of Tesla"** can be canceled for full refund, per the attachment that Tesla has send with title "Model Y Motor Vehicle Pre-Order Agreement"

Comment: How is this related to `stocks`, `stock-analysis`, or `stock-valuation`? Are you trying to decide what Tesla's stock will do based on how many cars are reserved? That seems to me like a rather tenuous justification for this to be on this SE.

Comment: @Acccumulation It might be that he wants to buy a Tesla and he's considering how long the deposit money will be out of his hands waiting for delivery. This question is reasonably on-topic for this site. It might be too specific to be of interest to you, but I would bet there are plenty of people who are interested in the answer to this question (if there is a good answer).

Comment: @NathanL They don't make nay mention of that, and that doesn't match the tags they chose. And technically, the deposit money will be out of their hands forever. If this is on topic, is "If I order something from China, how long should I expect delivery to take?" on topic?

Comment: @Accumulation "If I order something from China" could likely be closed as too broad without further clarifying information, but I would consider a similar question on-topic if asked in a way that it could be answered in a few paragraphs. I don't care whether this question is about stock valuation or purchasing as a consumer. Both are on-topic. The fact that it gives information for both cases broadens the interest it might receive.

Comment: Obviously the metric of how many Model Y were already reserved is extremely important in how the Tesla stock is going to perform. (slight nitpick there's no "reservation" with the Model Y, you have to actually order it, with a non-refundable deposit, which is why the number of deposits is likely fairly low at this point.

Comment: @nathan-l thanks , I have both objectives, I want to get a feeling how much orders and hopefully can gauge the stock price. And second , yes, i have made the so called order and trying to see when I will get the Tesla Y and making the financing/buying

Comment: @xyious you are correct about it that Tesla Y can be ordered, but
you may cancel your pre-order at any me, in which case you will receive a full refund of your Pre-Order

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be related to personal finance.

Comment: @RupertMorrish what in this question "does not appear to be related to personal finance"? Analyzing a company for investment? Weighing the cost of putting a deposit down on a car that may not arrive for a long period of time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any official sources of material information relating to the company's stock price will be listed in the company's prospectus along with filings with the Securities and Exchange Commission (see EDGAR at sec.gov).  You may also be able to deduce the situation looking at the company's quarterly financial statements, or ask a question if you are a shareholder on earnings calls.

However, Tesla have chosen not to disclose this information this time around.  I think in part because the 'Model 3' was the car for the people, and they were generally shocked by the large numbers of orders (in that they had underestimated it).  It was good PR to share the information at the time, but unless the model Y had even shockingly higher numbers, the benefit in terms of PR may be minimal, and could put people off buying a model 3 in the meantime.